# which .dll files do i need for Windows mobile 6 bluetooth development

Tags: visual-studio-2008, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6, dll

i'm developing bluetooth app on VisualStudio2008 windows mobile 6 sdk.I searched  that i will be needing

using microsoft.windowsmobile.sharedsource.bluetooth; for C#

I don't know what .dll files i need. Could any1 give me a dl link ? if possible some example codes on C# on how to discover other bluetooth devices would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use our library instead of that one (I've never used it).  See http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Before you answered i already tried inthehand.personel.dll and it works. But i can't find any relevant documents. Thanks :) cheers

Comment: Our documentation?  Or other?

We have a user guide in the release and online at http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20--%20User%20Guide.html  We also have a help-file full of all the class documentation included in the release and its also online at http://inthehand.co.uk/library/